# Exclude certain sites when using a label in Google Custom Search

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I'm implementing Google Custom Search on a site I'm working on.

The website is divided in subsites, with a parent site. It's done like this:

```
 - parentsite.com
  - parentsite.com/childsite1
  - parentsite.com/childsite2
  - parentsite.com/childsite3
  - parentsite.com/childsite4
```

When searching the site, I want the users to be able to filter out the results for each child site, and this I've done with refinement labels (so when you press the `Childsite 1` label, you will only get results from `parentsite.com/childsite1/*`)

**My question is:** I also want a label that **only gives the user results from the parent site**, but not from any of the child sites. Can I in some way also make the refinement label *exclude* certain url patterns?

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude urls in advanced site management by using a list of urls with one url per line. There are further options but the url is treated like a wild card so any url containing the part url you list will be excluded

1. start here and choose the CSE you own and wish to modify

https://www.google.com/cse/

2.from bottom of  ("Basics TAB") under the heading ["sites to add"] you should find an "advanced" link. its fairly intuitive from their bulk or one at a time...

1. check here for more info on url patterns

https://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71826

Comment: The question asks about excluding sites while using a label, though.  ~9 years later there still doesn't seem to be any way to do this.